# Crashlytics reports on macOS but not on iOS

Tags: ios, macos, firebase, crashlytics

I have an app which is available for iOS (V2.25) and macOS (V1.16). They share the same bundle identifier and the same GoogleService-Info.plist.

Both App are linked with „Crashlytics“ using Cocoa Pods. The iOS App is also setup for Firebase/Analytics. The xcode project is setup as desribed in the docs: dSYm with Dwarf for all configs, the build phase is configured, the crashlytics tests are run outside the debugger.

What happens is this: The macOS app (V1.16) reports crashes to Crashlytics as expected. The iOS app (V2.25) shows up in „Latest release“ and reports the number of crashes (s. 1st Screenshot), but it does NOT SHOW the crashes in the firebase „Crashlytics“! Even the version number V2.25 does not show up, (s. 2nd screenshot).

I have enabled -FIRDebugEnabled and I see the following log messages for the iOS version:

> 2020-05-21 20:48:26.492497+0200 Dictate[5662:1295303] [Crashlytics]
>   Version 3.14.0 (144) 2020-05-21 20:48:26.492630+0200
>   Dictate[5662:1295303] [Crashlytics] Running on iPhone10,5, 13.3.0
>   (17C54)
>       "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.14.0"; 2020-05-21 20:48:26.628957+0200 Dictate[5662:1295494] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports]
>   Packaged report with id 'c013eae8783c40528f5519358cc88828' for
>   submission 2020-05-21 20:48:26.629138+0200 Dictate[5662:1295494]
>   [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report 2020-05-21
>   20:48:26.629213+0200 Dictate[5662:1295494] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports]
>   Submitting async
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../v3/prepared/FD496B0D-947F-40DF-9075-5CCC8E978B2B.multipartmime
>   2020-05-21 20:48:26.629884+0200 Dictate[5662:1295494]
>   [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports:Event] Sending event. 2020-05-21
>   20:48:26.886129+0200 Dictate[5662:1295493] [Answers] Attempting to log
>   app_crashed 2020-05-21 20:48:27.419903+0200 Dictate[5662:1295498]
>   [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../v3/prepared/FD496B0D-947F-40DF-9075-5CCC8E978B2B.multipartmime
>   2020-05-21 20:48:27.420920+0200 Dictate[5662:1295498]
>   [Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful

So it looks like on the app side everything is OK. On the firebase portal side something seems to be wrong, the iOS (V2.25) reports seem to be dropped silently.

Please note that the behaviour is exactly the same when I migrate to the new „Firebase/Crashlytics“ instead of the older „Crashlytics“/„Fabric“ !

What is going wrong here ? Any ideas ? Thanks

[image: StreamView report]

[image: Crashlytics Report]

Comment: With AppId, do you mean bundle identifier? I had a similar issue, so just make sure the same bundle identifier is used everywhere. You could also try using two different GoogleService-Info.plist if it's two different apps.

Comment: Yes I mean bundle identifier. It is identical to both apps. Two plist files is not possible for me, because the bundleID is the same and Google forbids two Service plist files with same bundleID. What was your solution to the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebaser here -

I believe the issue is that you have the same bundle identifier in the same Firebase project for both your macOS and your iOS app. This is known to cause issues with reporting in one app or the other.

The workaround here would be to have another Firebase project to separate your macOS and iOS apps (and thus use different .plist files), or to have a different bundle identifier between the two.